# Classification: How to manage data sets where one data row depends on another data row

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, feature-construction

I am trying to classify  `heading`, `image` and `image caption`  of a webpage. I am preparing data by scraping selected URLs(around 1000) using `XPath` of `DOM elements` I need. Each data row in the CSV file contains `tag name, x-coordinate, y-coordinate, text-size` etc with three target labels `heading, image, image caption` but a text simply will not become image caption until unless it is under an image. Is there any way to create this dependency among rows.

Comment: What is the point of downvoting without telling why?

Comment: Use a linear chain [CRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) where the response (class) depends on the input and previous response. This is a type of sequential [graphical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model). The linked article also provides links to libraries. Welcome to the site and good luck!

Comment: @Emre waw this is amazing I did not know such thing exist. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are solving a *supervised classification* problem, that is, you train your model on a labeled sample. I can think of two approaches to this problem.

**I. Classify tags, use neighbor tags for the features**

For each tag you can calculate features like:

- (x, y) distances to the closest image
- (x, y) distances to the closest image *above this tag*
- number of images near this tag
- ...

Such features could be fed into any classifier like SVM or decision tree.

**II Classify pairs of tags**

For each tag $i$, you can consider all other tags $j$ and predict probability that $i$ is a caption of image $j$. This prediction may be based on concatenation of:

- features of $i$
- features of $j$
- joint features of $i$ and $j$, like vertical and horizontal distance from $i$ to $j$.

After these probabilities are predicted, you can classify $i$ as a caption indeed, if any of these probabilities exceeds some threshold.

Comment: Thanks, man. I spent some time learning neural networks and I will try to solve this problem using RNN but your idea helped me to think in a different way